# How to convert from wkt to wkb with spesifc srid (using shapely)

Tags: python, python-3.x, geospatial, shapely

I have a `pandas dataframe` (`df`) which contains column with text value (the value is WKT).

I want to convert this `wkt` to `wkb` of `srid 32636`

I have the following code (using `shapely` package):

```
def convert(wkt_text):
    p = shapely.wkt.loads(wkt_text)
    return p.wkb_hex

df['geo'] = df['geo'].apply(lambda x: convert(x))
```

But the code dosn't contains the srid values.

How can I convert the `geo` column which is `wkt` to `wkb` with `srid 32636` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
def convert(wkt_text):
    p = shapely.wkt.loads(wkt_text)
    from shapely import wkb
    return (wkb.dumps(p, hex=True, srid=32636))
```